# Is it possible to separate logback logs to separate appenders based on the log marker?

Tags: logging, logback, slf4j

I'm using Logback with SLF4J underlying in my application, and would like to send a couple of specific log messages to a file separate to the main log file. I don't really want to do this with log levels as that would mean I wouldn't be able to filter them out of the main log if the levels were adjusted (or rather I could but only by messing with both log level settings).

I know that logback offers a Marker option for log messages which sounds like the best approach however, I've tried various suggested approaches of filtering from the logback documentation an either get no logs, or two identical complete log files.

Any help much appreciated.

Have attempted:

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html:

```
<evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
<expression>
(marker != null) &amp;&amp; (marker.contains("MY_MARKER")
</expression>
</evaluator>
```

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">      
<evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
<expression>return message.contains("billing");</expression>
</evaluator>
<OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
<OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
</filter>
```

Desired outcome:

main.log:

- marker = fred - message1
- marker = burt - message2
- marker = ernie - message3
- marker = stever - message6

dave.log:

- marker = dave - message4
- marker = dave - message 5

Current behaviour:

main.log:

- marker = fred - message1
- marker = burt - message2
- marker = ernie - message3
- marker = dave - message4
- marker = dave - message 5
- marker = stever - message6

dave.log: 
 - marker = fred - message1
 - marker = burt - message2
 - marker = ernie - message3
 - marker = dave - message4
 - marker = dave - message 5
 - marker = stever - message6

Comment: I know I can do this using a custom Appender class which extends FileAppender and intercepts the ILoggingEvent, then does the check for the marker and only calls super.append(event) if the marker is correct,  but this seems a bit fabricated a package that is supposed to be so configurable via XML

Comment: Since I haven't had a response I'll go with the custom Appender.